# TTPhotoViewController in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ttphotoviewcontroller

I have been trying to integrate the TTPhotoViewController into a UITabBarController for a while but have not succeed.

The TTPhotoViewController works fine in a stand-alone fashion but I can't "press it" into a TabBar.

Has anyone come across an example that would do it?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I found an alternative solution than using Three20.  I ended up using the KTPhotoBrowser found at: https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser

I got KTPhotoBrowser working in about 15 minutes.  What I like most is its simplicity: just copy a few .h/.m files to your project. That's it...

It is only a photo browser though, no extra controls as Three20 has...

Also, with a couple of "release" removals, it is ARC compatible in iOS5, and storyboard plays well with it.  It comes with samples for local pics, flickr, or web site pics.

Answer (score 1):

Works in tabbarcontroller if you place the view controller inside a navigation controller, although it seems to have interfered with my subclassing of tabbarcontroller which I had implemented in order to have landscape orientation enabled for one of the views (to show video).